# chromecast worked well for a few days, but now buffers constantly

Tags: chromecast

I received my chromecast and it worked well for a couple of days. I watched full length films on Netflix and rocked out for hours on G music. Then suddenly, it started buffering every few seconds. I've tried resetting to factory defaults, but no luck. This leads me to believe that the issue it's in the router/chromecast communications or the chromecast hardware failed. I still have connectivity since it will try to play the movie or song, but stops often. I also have enough bandwidth since my phone handles it no problem. How can I debug the issue? Are there any suggestions for setting my home router?

Comment: I don't know what you mean by a different browser? To be clear this is for the chromecast device, not the chrome browser. My phone can stream without issue using the same wifi network the chromecast is on.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was with WiFi conflicts in an urban setting.

The biggest difference in bandwidth came with **disabling N on my router** and forcing it to stick to B/G. From my reading this helps since N attempts to grab 2 channels worth of bandwidth, fails, then tries a single one. With over 100 networks in the area, it probably never got 2 channels for N and constantly rolled back to G equivalent anyway, but only after failing.